# Sort list in reverse order extracted fields in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I got htis method:

```
private <T, V extends Comparable<V>> boolean isColumnSorted(List<T> gridResult, 
           Function<T, V> extractor) {
    List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(gridResult);
    sortedList.sort(Comparator.comparing(extractor));
    return sortedList.equals(gridResult);
}
```

but i don't know to to change it if  I would like to check if the list is sorted descending.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to return `true` if `gridResult` is sorted in *either ascending OR descending order*?

Answer (score 1):

Employ the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) method of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
sortedList.sort(Comparator.comparing(extractor).reversed());
```